# Read and write FASTA files with more information than id and sequence

Tags: fasta, python

I am trying to read a fasta file, manipulate is in Python (using BioPython) and then write it back.

The format of my sequences is like:

```
>k119_5 flag=0 multi=141.0706 len=473
AGGTTAGTCAGCACCGTTTCCGTGGTGCTGCCTTTCGCTTCAAAACCGACGGCGTCTATTACTGCATCCACGCCCCGGTGACCTGCCGTTTGTTCAATAATTGACTGTGCCGGATCGCTGTCTTCATCAAAATTAATCGGGATCGCGCCGTAGCGGTCGGCGGCGAAATGCAAGCGGTAGGGATGATGATCAACAACAAAAATCTGTTCCGCACCGAGCAACCGTGCACAGGCGATTGTCAACAATCCCACAGGACCAGCACCATAGACTGC
AACGCTTGAACCTTGTTGGATCTGCGCATTTTTTGCTGCCTGCCATGCCGTTGGCAGAATATCAGAAAGGAAAAGCGCTTTATCATCTGAAAGCAAAGGCGGTACTTTAAACGGCCCCACATTCCCTTTAGGGACGCGGACATATTCCGCCTGCCCACCAGGAACGCCGCCATACAGGTGACTATAACCAAACAATGCCGC
```

which is the result of the assmebly using Megahit. While trying to read, it only recognizes `k119_5` as the id, while I want the whole first line as the id of the sequence. Is vital information I want to keep!

Any ideas how to work with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `description` field in the [SeqRecord](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqRecord) object has the information you are looking for:

```
>> from Bio import SeqIO
>> s = SeqIO.read('genome.fasta', 'fasta') # single sequence fasta file
>> s.id
k119_5
>> s.description
k119_5 flag=0 multi=141.0706 len=473
```

Edit: as an aside, if you write a `SeqRecord` object using `SeqIO`'s `write` method, the FASTA header should contain the whole original header.